# is it possible to run async call to set a session in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I have a page that access Database running a heavy stored procedure and return a result,  the result will be displayed depending on a session variable Session["isShown"] for example.

I would like to using Ajax to call another page to set :

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST", "frmCancelWfSearch.aspx", true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

how to run frmCancelWfSearch.aspx asynchrounously to set that Session["isShown"]  to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement your server code in an `IHttpAsyncHandler` and also implement `IRequiresSessionState` so you have access to the session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use query string parameter say `isshow=true` or `isshow=false` and in your `frmCancelWfSearch.aspx` depending on the value of this parameter you can change the value of your session variable. You can send query string params when using `POST` like this: `xmlHttp.send("isshow=false");`