# Using AJAX to run actions while user is logged in

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, jquery

I'm currently programming a messaging system for a website using C# .NET as backend.

The messaging system is very similar to Facebook's web interface, which allows you to "chat" with another person, sending the messages via AJAX.

I've created a webservice (C#) that handles the actual sending message bit. I'm using JQuery to activate that service using the following code:

```
// generic webservice used to retrieve count from db
function SendMessageAJAX(taskID, sendeeID, sendeeType, recipientId, recipientType, content) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/WS/UIServices.asmx/SendMessage",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'content': content, 'SendeeType': sendeeType, 'SendeeId': sendeeID, 'RecipientType': recipientType, 'RecipientId': recipientId, 'taskID': taskID }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            // refresh chat area
            LoadMessages(false);
        },
        error: function () { alert("error"); }
    });
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing both the sendee / recipient info in my request. Obviously the code is very dangerous, as anyone can modify these values and impersonate any user.

I have the current logged-in user in a SESSION variable on my server side, but the code runs async, meaning the session variable is NOT defined when it runs.

What would the best way to safely run these actions via AJAX?

Comment: Client Side Security handling is **always** breakable, Do all you security check on server side

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the SESSION variables due to async ajax.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You can either encrypt your ajax requests like [this code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265305/Secure-Ajax-Authentication-without-SSL)  OR use SSL for website.
2. Implement your server code in an `IHttpAsyncHandler` and also implement `IRequiresSessionState` so you have access to the session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx

[is it possible to run async call to set a session in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071950/is-it-possible-to-run-async-call-to-set-a-session-in-asp-net)

Using ssl is always preferred but other options are also viable if you have time to implement.

Comment: I used the IRequiresSessionState implement and that worked great.

Comment: You can always vote-up or mark as answer if response helps you so that it will help others too.